# How to skip/ignore babel optimization for specific modules

Tags: babeljs, preact

I'm currently working on a preact app that connects with firebase.

My problem is this

[image: 30 seconds of my life....]

Since adding firebase to the project watch build times get seriously affected, jumping from an average of 10s to almost a minute.

From what I read online this is merely an information and not an error (kinda obvious with the 'Note:' bit).

Question: Is there any way to disable optimization for specific modules?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to disable styling optimization because you think it will have an affect on your build times or because you just want to know how you could possibly do that? If the former, it won't. If the latter, you need to split the babel loader into two -- one with `compact: true` set and the other without. You can then specify modules in the first that don't get extra whitespace after being transformed.

Comment: @rschristian it wont affect build times because babel still parses the modules? (if you care to answer I'll be happy to mark it as the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling `compact` mode on its own will not have any obvious performance benefits, especially not in the magnitude you're looking for.

Babel will still parse and transpile every module you throw at it -- what `compact` mode does is to give whitespace to the output. It makes it human readable. And that's all that warning is saying, that the module is so large that Babel is enabling `compact` mode itself for that module.